# Algpascal body?

Tags: algorithms, algorithmicx, algorithmic

I was going thorough the documentation of AlgPascal of package http://tug.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algorithmicx.pdf

My question here is when I am using

```
\For{k\gets 1}{K}
<command>
```

[image: Default for loop provided by AlgPascal]

How do I get :

```
\For{k\gets 1}{K}
<body>
\EndFor
```

Such that it intends the body not a single command?

```
\For{k\gets 1}{K} 
\Begin
% \begin{ALC@g}
\State $\mu_B \leftarrow \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m x_i$
\State $\sigma_B^2 \leftarrow \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m (x_i-\mu_B)^2$
\State $\hat{x_i} \leftarrow \frac{x_i-\mu_B}{\sqrt{\sigma_B^2+\epsilon}}$
\State $ y_i \leftarrow \gamma\hat{x_i} + \beta \equiv BN_{\gamma,\beta}(x_i)$
\State Using $\gamma$ and $\beta$ obtained from forward pass update:
\State  \hskip1.5em $\hat{y_i} \leftarrow \frac{y_i-\mu_B}{\sqrt{\sigma_B^2+\epsilon}}$
\State  \hskip1.5em $y_i = BN_{\gamma,\beta}(y_i)$  
\End
% \end{ALC@g}
```

[image: Running above code-snippet]

This seems to work fine but prints begin and end (which I don't want). Hskip can do the trick, but it is painful to do it everytime (writing a long thesis here).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Do you have a specific reason for using `algpascal`? The `algpseudocode` layout for example does the indentation of the full block by default (see the examples at the end of the manual).

Comment: @Marijn thanks. I like how `algpascal` has formatted the for loop (like `for{} to {} do`). So I was looking for way in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use `algpseudocode` instead of `algpascal` from the same package (`algorithmicx`) which seems to better satisfy your requirements when used with the `noend` option:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
    \For{$k\gets 1$ \textbf{to} $K$}
        \State $\mu_B \leftarrow \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m x_i$
        \State $\sigma_B^2 \leftarrow \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m (x_i-\mu_B)^2$
        \State $\hat{x_i} \leftarrow \frac{x_i-\mu_B}{\sqrt{\sigma_B^2+\epsilon}}$
        \State $ y_i \leftarrow \gamma\hat{x_i} + \beta \equiv BN_{\gamma,\beta}(x_i)$
        \State Using $\gamma$ and $\beta$ obtained from forward pass update:
        \State  \hskip1.5em $\hat{y_i} \leftarrow \frac{y_i-\mu_B}{\sqrt{\sigma_B^2+\epsilon}}$
        \State  \hskip1.5em $y_i = BN_{\gamma,\beta}(y_i)$  
    \EndFor
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output using algpseudocode with noend]

Please note that you have to rewrite your for loop with this (see code above). If you need this type of loop more often, you may decide to use an adapted command for it:

```latex
\algdef{SE}[FORto]{ForTo}{EndForTo}[2]{\algorithmicfor\ \(#1\) \textbf{to} \(#2\) \algorithmicdo}{}
```

This is based on the definition of `\For` from [`algpseudocode.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpseudocode.sty), but has been modified according to [`algpascal.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/algorithmicx/algpascal.sty) to allow a second parameter and to use math mode for typesetting its arguments. In this case, the `noend` option is already taken into account during the macro definition. A modified MWE would look like this:

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\algdef{SE}[FORto]{ForTo}{EndForTo}[2]{\algorithmicfor\ \(#1\) \textbf{to} \(#2\) \algorithmicdo}{}


\begin{document}

\begin{algorithmic}
    \ForTo{k\gets 1}{K}
        \State $\mu_B \leftarrow \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m x_i$
        \State $\sigma_B^2 \leftarrow \frac{1}{m}\sum_{i=1}^m (x_i-\mu_B)^2$
        \State $\hat{x_i} \leftarrow \frac{x_i-\mu_B}{\sqrt{\sigma_B^2+\epsilon}}$
        \State $ y_i \leftarrow \gamma\hat{x_i} + \beta \equiv BN_{\gamma,\beta}(x_i)$
        \State Using $\gamma$ and $\beta$ obtained from forward pass update:
        \State  \hskip1.5em $\hat{y_i} \leftarrow \frac{y_i-\mu_B}{\sqrt{\sigma_B^2+\epsilon}}$
        \State  \hskip1.5em $y_i = BN_{\gamma,\beta}(y_i)$  
    \EndForTo
\end{algorithmic}

\end{document}
```